# Delete duplicated rows by ROW_NUMBER function in where statement

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a database table that does not have ID column.

| COLUMN_TO_BE_UNIQUE | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | VALUE-1 |
| 1 | VALUE-1 |
| 2 | VALUE-2 |

I want to add UNIQUE INDEX for "COLUMN_TO_BE_UNIQUE", so first I'd like to delete all duplicates, but leave one row. How this can be achieved? I tried to use ROW_NUMBER, but does not seem to work.

Comment: please show your table structure. not all, just primary keys and basic data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the options I can suggest to add one new column that will temporarily play role of unique id. This column can be created as `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`, then you will use this column to identify rows that should be deleted.
Once deletion is done you can drop this column.